# Insert multiple rows into database

Tags: php, mysql, shopping-cart

We are a study group so we are unfortunately forced to invent the Wheel Again.

We are Building a simple database system with a cart function and checkout where when accepted the sale should be store

We have encountered a problem: We would like to send our product ids quantity and a order id witch is the same for every row - to our database

And we have absolutely no idea we have been looking and looking for an answer also here on this site. but we don't even know witch direction to go.

the data is shown as a list with the different variables like $sub_id and $quantity and one order ID witch is the same in every row.
so for instance we can have multiple sub_id's + $quantity and we want to send all of them to our database.

System is MySQL PHP HTML.

It all runs in a session called cart.

```
if($_SESSION['cart']) { //if the cart isn't empty
    //show the cart

    echo "<table id='overview' border=\"0\" padding=\"3\" width=\"100%\">"; //format the cart using a HTML table
    echo "<th>";

            echo "<th align=\"center\">Name</th>";
            echo "<th align=\"center\">color</th>";
            echo "<th align=\"center\">type</th>";
            echo "<th align=\"center\">price</th>";
            echo "<th align=\"center\">quantity</th>";
    echo "</tr>";

        //iterate through the cart, the $sub_id is the key and $quantity is the value
        foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $sub_id => $quantity) {    

                    //use sprintf to make sure that $sub_id is inserted into the query as a number - to prevent SQL injection
            $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM sub_product 
            WHERE sub_id = %d;",
                            $sub_id); 

            $result = mysql_query($sql);

            //Only display the row if there is a product (though there should always be as we have already checked)
            if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

                list($sub_id, $sp_id, $sub_color, $sub_colorcode, $sub_type, $sub_price) = mysql_fetch_row($result);

                $line_cost = $sub_price * $quantity;        //work out the line cost
                $total = $total + $line_cost - $discount;
                $moms = $total * 0.20;  
                    //add to the total cost

    ?>

        <?php
                echo "<tr font-size=\"xx-large\">";
            //show this information in table cell
                    echo "<td align=\"center\">$sub_id</td>";
                    echo "<td align=\"center\">$sp_name</td>";
                    echo "<td align=\"center\">$sub_color</td>";
                    echo "<td align=\"center\">$sub_type</td>";
                    echo "<td align=\"center\">$sub_price</td>";
                    //along with a 'remove' link next to the quantity - which links to this page, but with an action of remove, and the id of the current product
                    echo "<td align=\"center\"><a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?action=remove&id=$sub_id\"> - </a>$quantity<a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?action=add&id=$sub_id\">+</a></td>";
                    echo "<td align=\"center\">$line_cost</td>";


                echo "</tr>";

            }

        }
```

How to proceed?

Many times thank you in advance!-

Comment: Invent a modern wheel please - HTML5 and PHP 5.5!

Comment: If you're studying how use PHP effectively, you're starting out fifteen years in the past. `mysql_query` is not recommended for new applications because it's difficult to use correctly and small mistakes can lead to huge problems because of [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Applications like the sort you're creating here are notoriously difficult to maintain. The only thing you'll learn by building one is how awful that experience is compared to using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/).

Comment: okay we will note that.  thanks.